# Apply MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="True" for WebPart in SharePoint

Tags: list, web-part, related-list

I have a question regarding the `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack`

Is there any way I can add this feature to a ListViewWebPart, so that after making a selection in a related Lists Page it doesn't scroll up to the top of the top of the page on postback?

I have successfully implemented it for the entire page, but not for a webpart which has a defined height and has to be scrollable.

I think the Problem is addressed here but I don't quite understand how this is implemented on an existing web part:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9de5bb1a-2996-4010-9934-daa478a2638d/how-can-put-maintainscrollpositiononpostbacktrue-in-a-webpart